# How to Make docker compose status running,currently it stops after docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to make my docker-compose status up and running by trying below docker-compose yaml, but seems when I execute `docker-compose ps` , I see the container is stopped, how do I make my `docker-compose up` and running for infinite times

docker-compose.yml

```
  version: "3.7"
  services:
    execute:
      command: tail -f /dev/null
      image: abc/SREBlackBoxTester
      labels:
         - mylabelOne= "SREBlackBoxTester"
      volumes:
         - type: volume
           source: AWS_CREDENTIALS_FOLDER
           target: /home/scar/.aws
           source: SCAR_CONFIG_FOLDER
           target: /home/scar/.scar
           volume:
             nocopy: true
     command: bash -c "while true; do sleep 10; done"

    volumes:
        AWS_CREDENTIALS_FOLDER:
        SCAR_CONFIG_FOLDER:
```

Here goes Docker file

```
 FROM python:3.8-alpine

 RUN apk add zip unzip
 RUN addgroup --system scar && adduser -S -G scar scar
 USER scar

 WORKDIR /home/scar/
  RUN mkdir /home/scar/.scar && \
  mkdir /home/scar/.aws && \
  echo '[default]' > /home/scar/.aws/config && \
  echo 'region=us-west-2' >> /home/scar/.aws/config && \
  echo '[default]' > /home/scar/.aws/credentials && \
  echo 'aws_access_key_id=AX' >> /home/scar/.aws/credentials && \
  echo 'aws_secret_access_key=wctKx/KdRCSQ' >> /home/scar/.aws/credentials

ENV PATH=/home/scar/.local/bin:$PATH
ENV SCAR_LOG_PATH=/home/scar/.scar/

RUN pip3 install scar --user
CMD scar  init -n SREBlack -i image 


ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh
```

The output of docker ps -a

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                      

CREATED                  STATUS                              PORTS               
NAMES
f5af892b3b19        abc/image   "/bin/sh -c /bin/sh …"      
Less than a second ago   Exited (0) Less than a second ago                       
clever_wescoff
```

Comment: Does your image have a `Dockerfile`; can you add it to the question?  You shouldn't need to "keep the container alive", it will keep running as long as its main process (`ENTRYPOINT`/`CMD`) is running.  Deleting the override `command:` to let the command specified in the `Dockerfile` run would be a good idea.

Comment: provided ```Dockerfile```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a Docker container should be set up to run a specific program.  In most cases the default shouldn't be an interactive shell or an artificial `tail -f /dev/null` command.  In your example nothing is actually running the program you install.  You should change the end of the Dockerfile to actually run it

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
RUN pip install scar
CMD scar
```

and provide details like credentials through `volumes:` mounts.  (Consider whether embedding your AWS credentials into a Docker image has compromised them; anyone who has the image can do anything they're allowed to according to your IAM permissions.)

In the example you show the combination of `ENTRYPOINT` and `command:` leads to a non-sensical command line.  The Dockerfile documentation on [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) has technical details.  Since you specified a shell-format `ENTRYPOINT` it gets wrapped in `sh -c`, and then the `command:` from the `docker-compose.yml` file gets appended to that.  You wind up with something like

```
/bin/sh -c '/bin/sh' tail -f /dev/null
```

which just launches a shell (the "`tail ...`" is ignored), and since there's no input, it immediately exits.

In general Docker Compose is more oriented to running long-running applications, like databases or Web servers.  The SCAR documentation has an example of [running the tool in Docker](https://scar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scar_container.html).  For command-line tools like this, though, given the need to do things like manually push AWS credentials from the host into the container and to have root-equivalent permissions to run the tool at all, you might find it more convenient to run the tool directly on the host, maybe installed in a Python virtual environment.

Comment: i have updated ```Docker file ``` as per suggestion as you can see in question,but still scar lambda function not created after ```docker run abc/image``` shows out put as

Comment: apparently my scar command is not getting executed while i run docker run ,what should i do?

Comment: Delete the `ENTRYPOINT` line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose` file is setting two commands for the container

```
 command: tail -f /dev/null
```

and (is bash already included in the docker image)

```
command: bash -c "while true; do sleep 10; done"
```

you only can use one per service and you need to make sure that the command does not exit.

can you provide the logs of the containers

```
docker logs ${container_name}
```

Comment: thank you to you as well,your idea of checking logs was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
docker-compose up -d
```

-d flag stands for detached mode

Comment: thank you but it seems docker-compose is not the right thing here ,my approach was wrong ,but thanks for your response